# Why does my css not working on d3js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I am very new to d3js and I am having issues with making my css work. Here is my syntax:

my css

```
div.chart{
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-size:0.7em;
}
div.bar {
 background-color:DarkRed;
 color:white;
 height:3em;
 line-height:3em;
 padding-right:1em;
 margin-bottom:2px;
 text-align:right;
}
```

My d3js

```
$("document").ready(function(){

   d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/fwhm5",function(data){
     d3.select("body")
       .append("div")
          .attr("class","chart")
       .selectAll(".bar")
       .data(data.cash)
       .enter()
       .append("div")
          .attr("class","div")
          .style("width",function(d){return d.count/100 + "px"})
          .text(function(d){return Math.round(d.count)})


  })


})
```

Everything except the css is working.
Here is the codepen url https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzLMzb

Comment: What specifically are you trying to achieve and where are you having trouble? The problem might be that you are assigning class "div" instead of class "bar"?

Comment: What part is not working? As noted in the other comment, if you match the css selector to the class you give the new divs, it might work : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzLMQW (you give it the class "div", but select for ".bar" with the css)

Comment: Here you go: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xabeqm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.append("div")
      .attr("class","div")
```

Shouldn't that be

```
.append("div")
      .attr("class","bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a class named div instead of bar on line 10:

```
.attr("class","div")
```

This should be:

```
.attr("class","bar")
```